# Unauthenticated error on GraphQL for some ips, credentials: 'include' (SSR)

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, next.js, apollo

We have a communication between two services, an API and a client. The client is using NextJS and does partially SSR. the API is using a graphql module.

To authenticate we forward cookies from the client. We do this by passing the `credentials: 'include'` to a fetch query.

This works for 85% of the cases, however for 15% it doesn't. This only happens on the part where we send graphql requests from the client! (so after SSR)

This is the fetch configuration we're using (using apollo).

```js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

let globalApolloClient: ApolloClient<{}> | null = null;

function initApolloClient(
  initialState: {} = {},
  cookie?: string,
): ApolloClient<{}> {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return createApolloClient(initialState, cookie);
  }

  if (!globalApolloClient) {
    globalApolloClient = createApolloClient(initialState);
  }

  return globalApolloClient;
}


import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

function createApolloClient(
  initialState = {},
  cookie?: string,
): ApolloClient<{}> {
  const headers = cookie ? { cookie } : undefined;

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    credentials: 'include',    
    fetch,
    headers,
    uri: OurApiUrl,
  });

  return new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState),
    link: ApolloLink.from([httpLink]),
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
  });
}
```

The GraphQL context can not be created as our authentication cookie is missing in 15% of the cases. What could be the reason of this?

Comment: Some quick debugging ideas: does this occur if you switch to `cross-fetch` instead of `isomorphic-unfetch`? Also, is the API URL in the same domain as the client? If you switch from `include` to `same-origin`, does that change anything? My train of thought is that the polyfill for fetch might be causing the problem as the XHR `withCredentials` flag it uses doesn't work exactly the same as the fetch API `credentials` property.

Comment: Tried replacing it with cross-fetch but the volume of errors stays the same. Do you think that somehow the credentials might not passed when i use `include` rather than `same-origin` ?

Comment: What are you currently using to obtain the cookie on the server? I have a feeling that your cookie is only being set for the domain of your web application and not the GraphQL domain.

Comment: The cookie on the server is being parsed by Kong using https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/jwt/ after which it parses the cookie into a header that it sets (or anonymous when it couldn't parse). we currently get anonymous which means the cookie wasn't passed to kong (only happens when sending client side requests, and again, only for like 10-15% of our incoming requests, the rest works fine)